# How to avoid escaping when trying to replace $location.search?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, parameters

```
 const createParam = (key, value) => '?'+key+'='+value;

 const rebuildUrl = (linkUrl, params) => {
    TagsFactory.resetTickerTags();

    console.log('params', params);
    _.each(params, (param)=> {
        linkUrl += createParam(param.key, param.value);
    });

    console.log('linkUrl', linkUrl);
    // window.location.href = linkUrl;
    $location.search(linkUrl);
};

const checkForStoredLink = () => {
    Util.notEmpty(storedLinkParams) ? rebuildUrl('', storedLinkParams) : null;
};
```

---

```
storedLinkParams = [
    { key: "ticker",
      value: "AAPL" },
    // etc...
```

My function above will take in the params array and generate a string like this:
`/dashboard?ticker=AAPL?sort=trend?timespan=day?term_id_1=3010695?start_epoch=1473186060?end_epoch=1473358860`

My current URL looks like this:

`http://localhost/static/dashboard/app/#/dashboard?`

And once my function above reaches the `$location.search` line it ended up looking like this, which breaks the UI:

`http://localhost/static/dashboard/app/#/dashboard?%3Fticker=AAPL%3Fsort%3Dtrend%3Ftimespan%3Dday%3Fterm_id_1%3D3010695%3Fstart_epoch%3D1473186060%3Fend_epoch%3D1473358860`

Comment: why not delimit the parameters with `&`? If you use `&` you can pass `.search` an object rather than build the string yourself

Comment: `const createParam = (key, value) => '?'+key.trim() + '=' + value.trim();`

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh oh so the `$location.search` is looking for an object?

Comment: @gr3g thanks but the `trim` didn't do anything, the string that `linkUrl` becomes is already clean. It's what I want the search to be replaced with.

Comment: @LeonGaban it can also take a string but expects the params to be delimited by `&`

Comment: AH Thanks dude! I'm using this and it works now: `_.each(params, (param)=> {
            $location.search(param.key, param.value);
        });` Not sure if this is the best way, but you want to post the answer?

Comment: Glad to hear you've got it working :) added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$location.search` expects search parameters to be delimited by `&`. e.g.

`$location.search('param1=value1&param2=value2');` results in: `?param1=value1&param2=value2`

`$location.search('?param1=value1?param2=value2')` results in: `?%3Fparam1=value1%3Fparam2`.

If you start using `&` to delimit the params then your life can be even simpler, you can pass in an object and avoid any string building:

```
$location.search(_.fromPairs(_.map(params, x => [x.key, x.value])));
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fa7063yb/1/)

*Code above assumes the `_` is a recent version of lodash.js, if not:*

```
_.each(params, x => $location.search(x.key, x.value));
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fa7063yb/2/)

*To answer the question in the title:* If you really want to set raw urls yourself, then a solution to that could be to inject your own wrapper around `window.location`, but would not recommend

Comment: Thanks, but damn the `_.fromPairs` isn't updating my url :( also now my _.each is only updating the first param. Hmm not sure what happened...

Comment: @LeonGaban Sorry the `fromPairs` example was wrong, will update. [Here's another alternate solution](http://jsfiddle.net/fa7063yb/). Added some fiddles to the answer - hope this helps